# python syntax error with list filtering

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter an item from a list, and I'm getting a syntax error:
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

The code:

```
a['name'] = 'Dan'
b['name'] = 'Joe'

ppl = [a,b]
inputName = raw_input('Enter name:').strip()
person = [p in ppl if p['name']==inputName].pop()
```

any idea?

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't the complete code snippet, so could you specify which line throws the exception ) ?

Answer (score 8):

`[item for item in array]` 
not
`[item in array]`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use dictionary instead of list if you want to use 'name' key. It should look like this

```
    a = {'name':'Dan'}
    b = {'name':'Joe'}
    ppl = [a,b]
    for p in ppl:
        if(p['name']==inputName):
            person=ppl.pop(ppl.index(p))
```

Maybe there is a better way, more pythonic, but this one working ;)

Comment: I've added an answer similar to yours, but with a slight twist - it didn't fit nicely in the comment box..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bogna Anna Ka, use a dictionary.

This is a bit more pythonic in my opinion:

```
a = {'name':'Dan'}
b = {'name':'Joe'}
ppl = [a,b]
for key, value in ppl.iteritems()
    if(key == inputName):
        person = value
```

You iterate over the key-value pairs instead of creating a list of keys and iterating over them (which **for p in ppl:** implicitly does) and doing the get(), pop() and index()